# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'role_user.id' in 'on clause'

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I just want to get count from users based on roles table, but I when I try to code, I get the error message `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'role_user.id' in 'on clause'`

**this is the Controller**

```
 $countUser = DB::table(DB::raw('users'))
                    ->select(DB::raw('count(users.id) AS countUser'))
                    ->join('role_user', 'users.id', '=', 'role_user.user_id')
                    ->join('roles', 'role_user.id', '=', 'roles.id')
                    ->groupByRaw('role_user.role_id')->pluck('countUser');
```

In my SQL is work, this the code

```
SELECT r.name, count(u.id) AS countUser  
FROM users u, role_user ru, roles r 
WHERE u.id = ru.user_id 
AND ru.role_id = r.id
GROUP BY r.id
```

and this the result
[image]

How to fix it?

Comment: Make sure the column actually exists in your table. Maybe `'role_user.id'` should be `'role_user.role_id'`? Hard to tell without knowing your table structures/migrations

Comment: In your SQL you're using `ru.role_id`, so ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure your role_user table has an `id` field?

It looks like the table relates `users` to `roles` so I imagine it only has `user_id` and `role_id`.

Your join probably needs to be

```
->join('roles', 'role_user.role_id', '=', 'roles.id')
```

The SQL you added to your question shows the table having those fields and not an `id`.